# Using biblatex in R markdown without auto-creating "Reference" section

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown

My header looks as follows and works perfectly as intended:

```
---
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{float}
   - \usepackage{wrapfig}
   - \usepackage{graphicx}
   - \usepackage[fontsize=12pt]{scrextend}
   - \usepackage{fontspec}
   - \renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
   - \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_caption: true
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: SPP.bib
mainfont: ArialMT
geometry: margin=0.75in
---
```

However, the reference section already gets populated by the section name "References". Is there a way to stop that automated insertion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "References" section is automatically included if you define a `bibliography`. Here an excerpt from the template:

```
$if(biblatex)$
\printbibliography$if(biblio-title)$[title=$biblio-title$]$endif$

$endif$
```

Do you only want to change "References" into something else. Then it would be sufficient to add `biblio-title: ...` to you YAML header. If you want to suppress it completely, you have remove the quoted part in a copy of the template and use this copy instead. You can find the location where the template is stored via:

```
system.file("rmd", "latex", package = "rmarkdown")
#> [1] "/usr/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmd/latex"
```

Typically there are several files there:

```
list.files(system.file("rmd", "latex", package = "rmarkdown"))
#> [1] "default-1.14.tex"     "default-1.15.2.tex"   "default-1.17.0.2.tex"
#> [4] "default.tex"
```

The one with the highest version number (here `default-1.17.0.2.tex`) is used.

Comment: This is good. For now, I just needed a change. So I suppose I have to create a pandoc template and change it if I haven't created it? Where do I find this template? Thanks!